# Group action permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I have this triangle

$\hskip2,5in$[image]

In my notes I have that the permutation $(1 2)$ leaves $x$ unchanged and interchanges $y$ and $z$.

With the permutation $(1 2 3)$, $x$ maps to $y$, $y$ maps to $z$ and $z$ maps to $x$. I understand the mappings when we are looking at $(1 2 3)$.

However with $(1 2)$, why does $x$ remain unchanged?

Surely it would be mapped to $y$?

Comment: And what would $y$ and $z$ be mapped to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Trace a straight line from $3$ to the midpoint of $x$. Notice that $(12)$ could be seen as a spacial rotation around this line you've have drawn. That is, it leaves $3$ fixed and permutes $1$ and $2$. Therefore $x$ doesn't change.

$\hskip2,5in$[image]

Comment: So it is a reflection?

Comment: It's a spacial rotation.

Comment: What software did you use to draw this?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I used Corel Draw X6. I'm an artist on my free time.